# Is there a way to unbind jquery.address?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-address

How can I cancel jquery.address behavior?

```
$('a').unbind(); // Doesn't work for me..
```

Comment: `$('a').unbind('address');` ?

Comment: Are you using http://www.asual.com/jquery/address?

Comment: @J0HN Nope, I've got right after `$('a').address();` and there's no effect.

Comment: @Matt Mos def. There there's not a word regarding the issue.

Comment: Do you want to allow clicking on hyperlinks without redirecting?

Comment: Firstly, I don't want hash part of the url to be added. And further there's some other code responsible for ajax-loading etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just took a look at the library and there is no specific function is exposed for unbinding but I did see a private function call _unload but you cant access it..

anyways I would take a shout at using the autoUpdate function.. pass false to it and see..

Comment: Aaaaw yeah! `$.address.autoUpdate(false);` did the trick! But I don't quite understand for which purposes autoUpdate serves. Thanks anyway!

Comment: no problem.. remember to look at the plugin itself.. it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`unbind` works for me but it starts behaving like a normal like a normal anchor link and will redirect to the `href` set in it. If you don't its default behavior then you can try this.

```
//Please use a appropriate selector to select only the anchors to which you have
//applied address plugin
$('a').unbind().click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This will remove **all** event handlers bound to **all** links, which seems somewhat heavy-handed to me.

Comment: @Matt - I agree with you but it is just an example, obviuosly OP must have a class name or id to the anchors to select all of them.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for that I added necessary comment in my answer.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Normal link behaviour is right what I'm looking for, but `$('a').unbind();` doesn't work for me as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Jibiel - `unibind` unbinds all the event handlers attached to the element.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/6rMHh/

```
$('body').delegate('a','click',function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just stop load(); and hash still adding to the url.